# Authentication Practices with Node Express

Tags: mongodb, express, authentication, mongoose

I built a simple authentication system for my backend API with Express using Cookie-Parser and/or sending the Token to the front end.

It works like this: the user makes a post request to the login route with the username and password, and if it matches, he gets back both a .json response with the token and a cookie set with the token.

I thought it would be nice for the frontend development and authorization purposes to have the current user available in every successive request after the login. So, I set a middleware that searches if there is a token, tries to find a user in database with the corresponding ID, and set the user info (without the password) as a parameter in the request object (req.user).

What I wanted to know is:

Is it a bad practice to put the user info in the request? Does it lead to security problems? Or maybe the database query in every request could overload the server if the app scales to much?

This is my first backend API, I'm trying out different ways of doing things, but I'm not aware of the best practices in the field. Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

That is why there is encryption and in this context it is an ssl ticket. If you add login details to the request you NEED to make sure that the http response is encrypted. Once it is encrypted it is ok to do what you are doing. If it is not, an eaves dropper can snatch up that data from sniffing on your network.

Comment: Thanks! Does it mean that as long as the server is running on https there is no problem? Is there a simple way of doing this on Node? There is an options parameter in the setCookie function that makes it secure, but I would guess there is more to it than that?

Comment: Yes. Since all the data is encrypted and it is not very computationally feasible to obtain a private key from a public key thus being able to translate the request/response to something the attacker can read, it doesn't quite matter what you send on a secure connection. You need to generate an ssl ticket and use it in your node app. To use it download libraries named fs and https. Then make an httpsOptions which takes the path to your ssl folder's cert file and keys file. Then include this object in your connection. If you open a new question I will show you the required code.